# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not byte , upgrade to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to upgrade my code to python 3. 
Having some trouble with this line,

`output_file = open(working_dir + "E"+str(s)+".txt", "w+")`

```
output_file.write(','.join(headers) + "\n")
```

and get this error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

**What i've tried,**

```
  output_file.write(b",".join(headers) + b"\n")

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

ive also tried using `decode()` on the join, also tried using `r` and `w+b` on open.

How can i convert to `str` in python 3?

Comment: of what type is your variable `values`? `b""` seems not appropriate here since `write` expects a `str`, not `byte` (as the error says)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** to read on how to convert `bytes` to `string`, follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string) provided by Martijn Pieters in the 'duplicate' tag.

my original suggestion

```py
output_file.write(','.join([str(v) for v in values]) + "\n")
```

would give for example

```py
values = [b'a', b'b', b'c']
print(','.join([str(v) for v in values]))
# b'a',b'b',b'c'
```

So despite this works, it might not be desired. If the `bytes` should be **decoded** instead, use `bytes.decode()` (ideally also with the **appropriate** encoding provided, for example `bytes.decode('latin-1')`)

```py
values = [b'a', b'b', b'c']
print(','.join([v.decode() for v in values]))
# a,b,c
```

Comment: Seems to work, a mistake in my question :  I had "values" in my code, not "headers"

Comment: so you still can't write the `headers` variable? Or is it all working now?

Comment: it working, thank you.

Comment: This is not how you decode bytes values though. You concatenated `b'....'` strings, the `repr()` representations. Instead, use `bytes.decode()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for the comment. I made an edit to clarify on that - although the question does not ask explicitly for decoding, it is most likely the desired procedure.

Comment: They probably have little idea what they are doing, and are just trying the exception to go away. The question states they tried random things they found on Stack Overflow, at any rate. With a variable named `headers` this is probably HTTP so should be decoded as Latin-1, not UTF-8 (the default for `.decode()`.